# dynamically assigning function to __dir__ of an instance

Tags: python

I am trying to dynamically assign a function to `__del__` of an instance of a class so that it gets called when using dir() on that object.  I need `__dir__` to be unique for each instance of the class.  As a stripped down example, I have tried:

```
import types
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        def __dir__(self):
            print "in __dir__"
            return [arg]
        self.__dir__ = types.MethodType(__dir__, self, self.__class__)

foo = Foo('bar')
print dir(foo)
print
print foo.__dir__()
```

This prints:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']

in __dir__
['bar']
```

If I instead do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __dir__(self):
        print "in __dir__"
        return ['bar']

foo = Foo()
print dir(foo)
```

that outputs:

```
in __dir__
['bar']
```

as expected, but can not be customized for each instance of the class.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your comment I worked things a bit. I think this might be closer to the behavior you're looking for. Calling dir with no args gives all the names in the local scope and calling it on `__class__` gives all class names. This ignores the defined `__dir__` which can be called later on. I'm curious what you're using this for, maybe there is a simpler way to get the intended behavior?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        self.arg = arg
        print dir(self.__class__) + dir()

    def __dir__(self):
        return [self.arg()]


def dirfoo():
    return ["new thing"]

foo = Foo(dirfoo)

print dir(foo)
```

Comment: That would work in normal situations.  My case is kind of weird, though, because I actually need to call dir() during `__init__` and at that time I need to get the normal dir() output (without my own `__dir__` defined).  After that call is when I want to define my `__dir__` method.

Comment: dir(self.__class__) is the answer!!  I hadn't thought of doing that.  I ended up not even needed to store anything in an instance attribute.

Comment: The reason I have to do this is because I have overridden `__getattr__` so that, when accessing an attribute of the instance and that attribute doesn't exist, an object of a predetermined type will automatically get created for that attribute.

Comment: It worked fine for the most part, except that when I had to call dir() on the object, attributes call `__members__` and `__methods__` would automatically get created since, apparently somewhere, whether it be in a hasattr somewhere or a direct call to getattr, my `__getattr__` happily creates those attributes even though they shouldn't exist.

Comment: So in my `__dir__`, I now just return sorted(dir(self.`__class__`) + <the list of attributes I have already created with my `__getattr__` method.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Oh yeah, that stuffs fun! I've done that before to make dealing with xml easier.